# C# and MySQL - Method Returning a DataReader (or its contents)

Tags: c#, mysql, methods, datareader

Throughout my program, I'm going to be repeatedly using the SELECT command (of MySQL). Each time, I have to establish the connection and stuff. I'm thinking of making a method that receives a SELECT command string and returns the argument's equivalent DataReader. I'm thinking this'll help me reduce the large chunk of code I have to produce each time.

I want to use it in such a way that:

```
MySqlDataReader myReader = myObj.loadDataToReader("SELECT * FROM tblSample");
```

And then, I can manipulate `myReader` like a regular MySqlDataReader. However, I'm concerned about the fact that the connection must be open when using a datareader, and of course, the thing about it (the reader and the connection) being needed to be closed and all (a conventional security measure, I believe). I've been looking at things in the internet, and I can't seem to find a hint of how to do this.

I'm trying and I have the following line of code:

```
public MySqlDataReader loadDataToReader(string selectCommand)
{
    MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
    string myConnectionString = "Data Source = " + server + "; User = " + user + "; Port = 3306; Password = " + password + ";";
    string useDataBaseCommand = "USE " + dbName + ";";
    using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(useDataBaseCommand + selectCommand, myConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myConnection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return myReader;
        }
    }
}
```

And in another class's method, I create an object to be able to use the method defined above, in such a way that it looks like this:

```
string selectTableCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE Username = \'" + txtID.Text + "\' AND Password = \'" + txtPassword.Text + "\';";
MySQLOperations objSQLOperations = new MySQLOperations("localhost", "root", "mypass", "mydatabase");
MySqlDataReader myDataReader = objSQLOperations.loadDataToReader(selectTableCommand);
if (myDataReader.Read() && txtPassword.Text.Equals(myDataReader["Password"].ToString()))
     { /* do something */ }
else
     { /* do something */ }
```

However, I get a message saying "Invalid attempt to read when reader is closed!"
How can I correct this and make it work? Or rather, is there a much more appropriate way to do this? And how am I going to make sure my connection/reader is closed after using them?

Comment: Use a DataTable instead. Load the reader into the datatable i.e. `var dt = new DataTable(); dt.Load(myReader);` then return the DataTable to the caller to do stuff with it.

Comment: `DataSet` or `DataTable` are often a better choice than `DataReader`.  Also you should be parameterizing your SQL statements, not concatenating them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'm going to use DataTable instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your method generic and inject a function to work on the reader, then return the function's output rather than the reader:

```
public T LoadDataToReader<T>(string selectCommand, Func<IDataReader,T> ProcessResults)
{
    string myConnectionString = "Data Source = " + server + "; User = " + user + "; Port = 3306; Password = " + password + ";";
    string useDataBaseCommand = "USE " + dbName + ";";
    using (var myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        using (var myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = useDataBaseCommand + selectCommand;

            using(var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
               return ProcessResults(myReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also made some other changes:

- `IDataReader` implements `IDisposable`, so I added the using statement for the reader
- I used the ADO.NET interface methods for creating the command rather than the constructor
- I removed the catch block, because the connection close happens automatically when you leave the using block, and UI code (e.g., `MessageBox`) does not belong in DAL code.  This should instead be done as a try/catch around the call to this method.
- I capitalized the first letter of the function to make it consistent with .NET coding standards

Then, you simply use it as follows:

```
public static string GetStringData(IDataReader reader)
{
  var ord_name = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");

   if(reader.Read())
     return reader.GetString(ord_name);

   return null;
}

public static IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos(IDataReader reader)
{
   var ord_name = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
   var foos = new List<Foo>();

   while(reader.Read())
     foos.Add(new Foo {Name = reader.GetString(ord_name)});

   return foos;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var program = new Program();
   try
   {
      var name = program.LoadDataToReader("SELECT name FROM thename", GetStringData);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
   try
   {
      var foos = program.LoadDataToReader("SELECT foos FROM footable", GetFoos);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

Additionally, you should probably pass the connection string in rather than building it from fields.  Alternatively, you could just set a field for the entire connection string (built only once rather than every execution) and use that.

Also, the database can be set in the connection string with either `Initial Catalog` or `Database`, which would be preferable to prefixing the select statement with a `USE database` clause.

Comment: I've decided I'm going to stick with what I did above, just going to change it to DataTable. Still, thank you, Sir. I'll probably be able to use this some way, some day.

Comment: @Jill Keep in mind that both `DataSet` and `DataTable` are `IDisposable`.  They're both pretty heavy objects memory-wise and query-wise, since the data adapter has to perform additional steps to determine the result set schema.  If you know the schema ahead of time a data reader is better to use, though using an ORM like Entity Framework or nHibernate would be better than any of the proposed options.